# sendmessage callback error in visual studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

sendmessage callback error in visual studio 2012
I am recieving following errors in this C function?

```
error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
warning C4100: 'wParam' : unreferenced formal parameter 
warning C4100: 'hwnd' : unreferenced formal parameter



      LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd,UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
        {
        switch (message) {
        case WM_COPYDATA:
                  {

        COPYDATASTRUCT* copy_data = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)(lParam);

                    const char* str = (const char* )(copy_data->lpData);
                    /* Also fixed the parameter list for "%.*s" */
            printf("Message (%u): %.*s\n", copy_data->dwData, (int)copy_data->cbData, str);
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: And the question is? Believe it or not it's not obvious.

Comment: Please decide, is this a C++ or a C program? The solution is different depending on language. What is the extension of the source file (i.e. `.cpp` or `.c`)?

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you told the compiler to treat warnings as errors, and you have two warnings about arguments that is not used in the function.

The simplest solution is to actually skip naming those arguments, like so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT message, WPARAM, LPARAM lParam)
```

---

For a solution working in C, then you have to actually *use* the arguments, even if you don't do anything with them. This can be done with e.g. using them in an expression and throw away the result, like

```
(void) hwnd;
(void) wParam;
```

Or use the macros defined in `winnt.h` (which should be included for you by default) for this:

```
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hwnd);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
```

See e.g. [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163805.aspx).

Comment: Last time I checked that would only work in C++, the OP says his code is C.

Comment: @john It *is* tagged C++ as well.

Comment: Well error is still the same, What to do to skip this errors? I have tried jaochim suggestion but it does not work

Comment: function is corrected, there was no return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;

Comment: @Geeko In the future, please include your *complete* and *unedited* error messages in the questions. It will help a lot.